# How Neural Networks' prediction in R works on periodic data?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-networks, forecasting, prediction

I have a data set `x`

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7)
```

As my entries with a period of 4. And now if I call

```
library(forecast)
forecast(nnetar(x))
```

Then neural networks should predict

```
# 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9
```

Knowing there is a periodicity. But the result observed is something like

```
# 7 8 9 6 7 5 4 9
```

So, any answer on how neural networks' prediction works for periodic data?

Comment: Try with `x <- ts(x, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 4)`.

Comment: This is not an example of what "periodic" means.  One might characterize your data as "locally constant."  One could also characterize it as constant after lag-4 differences ("seasonal differencing").

Answer (score 1):

You need information about the time and the seasonality. One way is to create a quarterly time serie.

```
x <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7) 
x <- ts(x, start = c(1980, 1), frequency = 4)

library(forecast)
out <- forecast(nnetar(x), h=10)

plot(out)
```

[image]